# Make a local variable value global in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, global-variables

I have the following code.In this code i am able to get the string value like 1,2,3 etc through the use of eventHandling.How i get the value is not important for now.What i need now is to be able to access this string value outside the page_load event like in the function `myfun()` as given below.How do i acheive that.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
    lcont lc = mymaster.getlcont();
    lc.myevent += delegate(string st)
     {
         //slbl.Text = st;

         string str =st;
      }
 }

   protectd void myfun()
   {
     //i want to access the string value "st" here.
   }
```

Comment: Define it in the class scope not the delegate scope or pass it as a parameter to `myfun()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways as i see:

1) Pass as param:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
    lcont lc = mymaster.getlcont();
    lc.myevent += delegate(string st)
     {
         //slbl.Text = st;

         string str =st;
         myfunc(str); // pass as param
      }
 }

 protectd void myfun(string str)  // see signature
 {
     //i want to access the string value "st" here.
 }
```

2) Make a class variable:

```
string classvariable;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
    lcont lc = mymaster.getlcont();
    lc.myevent += delegate(string st)
     {
         //slbl.Text = st;

         string str =st;
         classvariable = str; // set it here
     }
}

protectd void myfun()
{
   //i want to access the string value "st" here. // get it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you would simply declare the variable you want global outside of the scope  of the functions.

IE: Whatever / wherever they are contained.

```
string st; // St is declared outside of their scopes
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
   protectd void myfun()
   {
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it public:

**public** - the member can be reached from anywhere. This is the least restrictive visibility. Enums and interfaces are, by default, publicly visible

**Example**

```
<visibility> <data type> <name> = <value>;
```

or

```
public string name = "John Doe";
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your global (or class?) variable before the Page_Load or right after the Class declaration.

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   private string str = "";

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

      hfm mymaster = (hfm)Page.Master;
      lcont lc = mymaster.getlcont();
      lc.myevent += delegate(string st)
      {
          //slbl.Text = st;

         str =st;
      }
   }

   protectd void myfun()
   {
     //i want to access the string value "st" here.

     //value of st has been passed to str already in page_load.
     string newString = str;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A single change can make it possible. declare str as global variable

```
public class Form1
{
     string str = "";//Globel declaration of variable
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```